# Range Doppler Maps

Tags: fourier, doppler

I would like to understand from a high point of view how these maps are computed.

- On the y-axis we have m/s and in the x-axis the range.

  I read something about the Fourier transform etc, but I don't have a clear point of view.
- In my specific case I'm dealing with radar raw data and I need to create the range doppler maps.

  I have the code but I would like to understand very well how these maps are generated.

Comment: It it a pulsed or a continuous wave radar system?

Comment: It is a frequency modulated continuous wave radar system, ( FMWC radar )